# How to check whether registered component was previously resolved?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Long story short, I am working on Windsor modification, which would allow me to override registered services. Override in a true sense, where if you register a new service with existing name, old registration is removed and new one is added in its place.

However, I want to also implement some safety checks. In particular I want to forbid this behavior, if old component was previously resolved (to make sure, that I do not leak components and get consistent dependency resolution). Now, how do I check for that, if I have access to both `IHandler` of old component and `IKernel`? For now I use `ICommissionConcern` to flag all `ComponentModel`s that were created:

```
class NameOverrideContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        model.Configuration.Attributes.Add(NameOverrideSubsystem.CreatedFlag, null);
        model.Lifecycle.Add(new NameOverrideComission());
    }

    class NameOverrideComission : ICommissionConcern
    {
        public void Apply(ComponentModel model, object component)
        {
            model.Configuration.Attributes[NameOverrideSubsystem.CreatedFlag] = "Component created";
        }
    }
}
```

Then is simply check this flag. Is there a better way?